# how to use foreign key in laravel 5.1 migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-5.1

I need to use foreign key for my database but I can't do this, after run migration command in command line, I get this error :

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `samples` add
>   constraint s   amples_supplier_id_foreign foreign key (`supplier_id`)
>   references `suppliers` (`id`))
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add
>   foreign key constraint

Samples migration :

```
Schema::create('samples', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->Increments('id',true);
            $table->string('variety',50);
            $table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers');
            $table->string('lot_number');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->integer('amount');
            $table->integer('unit_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('unit_id')->references('id')->on('unit');
            $table->string('technical_fact');
            $table->string('comments');
            $table->string('file_address');
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Supplier migration :

```
Schema::create('suppliers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->Increments('id',true);
            $table->string('supplier',50);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I try to that with new migration for samples, but unsuccessful :

```
Schema::create('samples', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->Increments('id',true);
                $table->string('variety',50);
                $table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned();
                $table->string('lot_number');
                $table->date('date');
                $table->integer('amount');
                $table->integer('unit_id')->unsigned();
                $table->string('technical_fact');
                $table->string('comments');
                $table->string('file_address');
                $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
                $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('samples', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers');
            $table->foreign('unit_id')->references('id')->on('unit');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category');
        });
```

I try to fix length of the primary key to 10, but unsuccessful again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Order matters.

You want to be sure that your "suppliers" table exists before attempting to reference a column on that table as a constraint.

So If you want to set your foreign key Constraint while creating your table then make sure that you create the "**suppliers**" migration first, and the "**samples**" migration afterwards:

```
php artisan make:migration create_suppliers_table --create=suppliers
php artisan make:migration create_samples_table --create=samples
```

...add schema code to your migration files. and then:

```
php artisan migrate
```

---

If you don't want to worry about the order in which the tables are created then do your create_table migrations first, without the foreign key constraints, and then do an additional migration to add your foreign keys.

```
php artisan make:migration create_samples_table --create=samples
php artisan make:migration create_suppliers_table --create=suppliers
php artisan make:migration alter_samples_table --table=samples   <-- add your foreign key constraints to this migration file
```

...add schema code to your migration files. And then migrate using:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 5):

At last generate a migration for the table keep in mind that they should be in order if you feel any diffuculties just name ur table_foreign_keys

```
 Schema::table('samples', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers');
            $table->foreign('unit_id')->references('id')->on('unit');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category');
        });
```

place all foreign keys related here at last and run

Answer (score 2):

try like this way

```
Schema::table('samples', function($table) {
        $table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers');
        $table->integer('unit_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('unit_id')->references('id')->on('unit');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category');
    });
```

Comment: I say do this, but unsuccessfull

Comment: First execute supplier migration,then sample migration.Cause without supplier migration supplier_id will not work as foreign key

Answer (score 1):

KorreyD say true ! , but I created migrations, and then renamed the migration to reorder them, It's so simple :

**Before renamed :**

Supplier migration : 2015_08_**21**_104217_supllier_table.php

Samples migration : 2015_08_**22**_102325_samples_table.php

**After renamed :**

Samples migration : 2015_08_**21**_102325_samples_table.php

Supplier migration : 2015_08_**22**_104217_supllier_table.php

my problem solved ! because supplier migration run before the samples migration

Comment : I try to this with reflector, that renamed any where that used migration name

Comment: I've been struggling with these things too. Take a look at laravelsd.com. You can create a database structure there and then export it all. It creates migrations and puts all the key bindings in the last file.

Comment: Great! yes that works too.  I didn't mention that method since im not a laravel expert and I'm not sure of any issues that may arise from renaming migration files.

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is correct however the easiest way is to create your migrations files a usual. You will have e.g. 2019_01_21_123456_create_table_one_table.php ...

I renamed them all

```
2019_01_21_0010_create_table_one_table.php
2019_01_21_0020_create_table_two_table.php
2019_01_21_0030_create_table_three_table.php
2019_01_21_0040_create_table_four_table.php
```

Now if I need to add a migration before table_two and after table_one I can simply change it to

```
2019_01_21_0015_create_table_five_table.php
```

Now the migration order will be

```
2019_01_21_0010_create_table_one_table.php
2019_01_21_0015_create_table_five_table.php
2019_01_21_0020_create_table_two_table.php
2019_01_21_0030_create_table_three_table.php
2019_01_21_0040_create_table_four_table.php
```